# Appmaker onInputChange not updating datasource

Tags: google-app-maker

I was looking at the tutorial from AMU at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKz3z6gw1fQ, which outlines how to use a search box to narrow down records, and wanted it to reload the datasource onInputChange instead of onValueChange so the user doesn't need to change focus for the reload to happen. Simply putting the 'Reload Datasource' onInputChange doesn't work.  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else that has this issue, I was able to solve it by adding

widget.value = widget.value;
widget.datasource.load();

Don't know why that would be necessary, but it worked.